# Bootstrap dropdown-menu unhover when in submenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a dropdown-menu working with javascript on hover.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('ul.nav li.dropdown').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn(500);
  }, function() {
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut(500);
  });
});
```

and I set on hover style

```
i.dropdown:hover
{
  background-color: rgb(28,181,181);
}
```

here is the problem, when i am hovering the dropdown menu not the toggle, the toggle style will go back to normal. since it still register i am still hovering the toggle.

```
<li style="width:20%" class='dropdown'>
  <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle disabled"  id="dropdownMenu2"><div align='center'><b>example</b></div></a>
  <ul class='dropdown-menu' style='width: 100%;padding:0px;border-width:0px;' aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
    <li><a href="" style='height:45px;padding-top: 10px;'><div align='center'><b>example2</b></div></a></li>
    <li><a href="" style='height:45px;padding-top: 10px;'><div align='center'><b>example3</b></div></a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Look at [this](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/37490/). Is this what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this snippet , is this what you need ?

```js
$('li.dropdown').hover(function() {
  $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn(500);
}, function() {
  $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut(500);
});
```

```css
li.dropdown
{
  transition-duration:0.7s;
}
li.dropdown:hover
{
  background-color: rgb(28,181,181);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<li style="width:20%" class='dropdown'>
  <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle disabled"  id="dropdownMenu2"><div align='center'><b>example</b></div></a>
  <ul class='dropdown-menu' style='width: 100%;padding:0px;border-width:0px;' aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
    <li><a href="" style='height:45px;padding-top: 10px;'><div align='center'><b>example2</b></div></a></li>
    <li><a href="" style='height:45px;padding-top: 10px;'><div align='center'><b>example3</b></div></a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: not this, i want when i am hovering the menu not the toggle. the toggle goes back the original style. but thanks for answering

Answer (score 0):

Please check this.

```js
$('li.dropdown').hover(function() {
  $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn(500);
}, function() {
  $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut(500);
});
```

```css
li.dropdown:hover{
  background-color: rgb(28,181,181);
}
.dropdown a{
  display:block;
  line-height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<li style="width:20%" class='dropdown'>
  <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle disabled"  id="dropdownMenu2"><div align='center'><b>example</b></div></a>
  <ul class='dropdown-menu' style='width: 100%;padding:0px;border-width:0px;' aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
    <li><a href="" style='height:45px;padding-top: 10px;'><div align='center'><b>example2</b></div></a></li>
    <li><a href="" style='height:45px;padding-top: 10px;'><div align='center'><b>example3</b></div></a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: i want when i am hover on the menu not the toggle. the toggle style goes back, because style still register me hovering the toggle when i am hovering on dropdown menu

Comment: what you want to do i am not understand exactly.

Comment: you want to give style in dropdown menu also...?

Comment: When i Hover the toggle of the dropdown menu, the toggle will change color and display the menu. when i have my mouse over on the menu not the toggle, the toggle will then return the original style. sorry for bad communication